# Is $B \setminus (A+x) = B \cap (A+x)^c = B \cap A^c + x$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$( arbitrary). Is $B \setminus(A+x) = B \cap (A+x)^c = B \cap A^c + x$?($A+x=\{a+x: a \in A \}$ and $A\setminus B = A \cap B^c$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is true. Let $A=B=[0,1]$, $x=0.5$. Then $A+x=[0.5,1.5]$, and $B\setminus(A+x)=[0,0.5)$. But we know $B\cap A^{c}=\emptyset$, therefore $B\cap A^{c}+x=\emptyset$. So the two sets are not equal.

Comment: user32240: with assumptions above does $(A+x)^c = A^c+x^c$ or $(A+x)^c = A^c+x$ hold? What about does $B \cap (A+x) = B \cap A+x$ hold?

Comment: @alvoutila: Let $x=0$, then $A^{c}\not=A^{c}+R/\{0\}$ in general. The second one looks fine to me. The third is not right - Let $B=[3,4],A=[1,2]$, then $B\cap A+2=\emptyset$, but $B\cap (A+2)=B$.

Comment: User32240: What about if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n $, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and A is measurable; how to show that $x+A$ is measurable? some hint.

Comment: @alvoutila: I suggest you take a look at translation invariance of Lesbegue measure.

Comment: User32240: Yes, but one have to use also information that it is enough to prove that $m*(A) \geq m*(A \cap E) + m*(A \setminus E)$

Comment: User32240: Yes, but one have to use also information that it is enough to prove that( if $A \subset R^n$ is measurable) $m^*(A) \geq m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \setminus E)$. Am I right? But now I try to figure out if $B \cap (A+x) \subset B \cap A+x$ and if $B \cap (A+x)^c \subset B \cap A^c+x$, because if thats true, then you can use monotoonsus of measure and you get; $m^*(B) = m^*(B \cap A) + m^*(B \setminus A) \geq m^*(B \cap (A+x)) + m^*(B \setminus (A+x))$ Am I right?

Comment: @alvoutila: That is the long way. Think this way; $A$ is Lesbegue measurable if and only if for any $\epsilon$ there is $K\subset A\subset O$ such that $m^{*}(O-K)<\epsilon$. Now both $K$ and $O$ can be translated and the result would hold for $A+x$ as well. Here $O\in F_{\delta}, K\in G_{\sigma}$.

Comment: I do not know how to put your idea into proof. Can you show the idea as a proof? My proof doesn't work because $B \cap (A+x) \subset B \cap A +x$ is false( for example if $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[1,2]$ and $x=1,5$ then $B \cap (A+x)=[1;1,5]$ but $B \cap A +x = \{1,5\}$

Comment: @alvoutila: Try to read Chapter 2 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.